# Can you top up 10000 won in my card?

Tags: grammar

If I want to ask to a clerk in a convenience store to top up my T-Money card can I ask with the following:

> 사장님. 카드에 만원을 충전해 주세요/주겠어요?

1. Is it grammatically correct?
2. Does it sound natural to say?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use 주시겠어요 instead of 주겠어요, but anything else looks correct.
2. Usually, people working in a convenience store is a part-time worker. You might use 사장님 in a restaurant to call any worker, but because it's clear that the worker is aware you are talking to them, 사장님 sounds unnecessary here. And I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct or applicable to any case, but for a non-human object in a sentence, the postposition like '-을/를' is usually omitted. So I would say '카드에 만 원 충전해 주세요/주시겠어요?'

Comment: Why 주시겠어요? Honorific?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, it's 충전하다(to recharge) + 주다(to do as a favor) + -시- (honorific) + -겠다 (would) + -어요? (for questioning). It's the same reason why you should say "충전해 주세요" instead of "충전해 줘요". -시- usually goes with -어요/-해요, and almost always if you talk about someone unfamiliar or about someone with higher status than you.